Wordpress Ajax gets 400 bad request error
I try to run a ajax in wordpress but get 400 bad request error in firefox
This is my code:
function sendsms_function(){
    echo 'hello';
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendsms', 'sendsms_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_sendsms', 'sendsms_function');

And jquey code:
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
    data: {
           action:'sendsms', 
    },
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});

I tried this also:
jQuery.get('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',{'action': 'sendsms'}, 
function (msg) { alert(msg);});

I need to be solved my problem.
This anorher page I created for Test:
https://alooamlak.com/text-ajax/
And all code:

<button type="button" class="btn woocommerce-Button button" id="sendsms" name="sendsms" >send</button>
                
<?php

function get_data() {
    echo  "test";
    wp_die();  //die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'get_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_data', 'get_data' );

 ?>
 
 
 <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#sendsms").click(function(){
         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", //this is wordpress ajax file which is already avaiable in wordpress
            data: {
                action:'get_data', //this value is first parameter of add_action
                id: 4
            },
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
 </script>


Your AJAX request doesn't go to /text-ajax/ - so the code where you tried to add the AJAX action, doesn't even execute for that request. This does not belong into the page's code, it should go into the functions.php of your theme.

Is this a PHP problem or an AJAX problem? Did you check whether your server's or application's error log holds more details?

I put my function in "functions.php" it solved. Thanks alot
